# Selecting correct option with Javascript in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with Internet Explorer not correctly selecting an option when a javascript event is triggered.

I track the events of a marker on a google map. When the marker is moved, I want the right country to be chosen from a select list.

Part of the code that switches the country selection:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//...
document.getElementById("id_country").value = country;
//...
</script>
```

It works just fine in Google Chrome. I know that the country name that is being returned by the map matches the ones in the option field values. In Internet Explorer, nothing happens.

```
<select id="id_country" name="country">
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
    <!--...-->
</select>
```

How do I get Internet Explorer to select the correct option (without using jquery)?

Comment: On an entirely unrelated note, country dropdowns like that always make me chuckle. How many customers are you expecting from the Åland islands and Afghanistan? :)

Comment: version of IE might be helpful

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fSVGD/2/ this is working for me using IE7 and IE8 browser modes in IE9 (unfortunately I don't have actual copies of the older browsers installed).

Comment: What you are doing seems completely correct. OLDER browser might want you to loop over the options and set the matching option's selected to the boolean true

Comment: Sapph and mplungjan, you are right. It does indeed work just fine in Internet Explorer. The problem was entirely different: in Internet Explorer, I have a different language setting. Google Maps returns the country name in a locale-specific language with their geocoding api. I will have to set the right language when I make the API request.

Comment: @Reggie so perhaps I should write that as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[selectedIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp) property would work but as Afshin said You need to iterate options first.

```
var elCountry = document.getElementById("id_country");
var options = elCountry.options;
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].value == country) {
        elCountry.selectedIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would do `if (options[i].value === country) { options[i].selected=true; }` but only to please really old browsers

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the options collection of document.getElementById('id_country') and set the matching option's "selected" attribute to the string "selected"

Comment: That is completely backwards way to do that. You hopefully mean "loop over the options and set the matching option's selected value to the boolean true"

Comment: @mplungjan: afshin is correct saying "set the option's 'selected' attribute to the string 'selected'". It's done like this: `options[i].setAttribute("selected", "selected");`. However that is unusual to do.

Comment: @RoT it SEEMS to work, however Fx4 tells me BOTH the selected via HTML and the setAttibute one has selected="selected" It does work in IE http://jsfiddle.net/BTrAY/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code sample demonstrating @afshin's answer (thank you!):

```
function setCountryOption(country) {
  const selectEl = document.getElementById('id_country');
  const options = selectEl.options;

  for (let i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (options[i].value == country) {
      options[i].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
    }
  }
}
```